# Questions on the one point compactification on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

I have a few questions from the following paragraph of Topology by James Munkres page 377.

Let $C$ be a compact subspace of $S^2$ and $b\in S^2-C$.

The paragraph:

The stereographic projection $h: S^2-b \to \mathbb{R}^2$ can be extended
to a homeomorphism $H$ of $S^2$ with one-point compactification $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\{\infty\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, merely by setting $H(b)=\infty$. If $U_{\beta}$ is the component of $S^2-C$ containing $b$,
then $H(U_{\beta})$ is a neighborhood of $\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\infty$. Therefore, $V_{\beta} = h(U_{\beta} - b)$ is unbounded; since its complement $\mathbb{R}^2-V_{\beta}$ is compact, all other components of $\mathbb{R}^2-h(C)$ are bounded.

My Questions:

1) By $V_{\beta}$ being unbounded, does this simply mean that it does not contain the point $\infty$? From this, can we conclude that any subset
of the compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ not including $\infty$ is bounded?

2) How different are the topologies of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\{\infty\}$?

3) I am not sure why the complement $\mathbb{R}^2-V_{\beta}$ is compact, and it seems to me that we are using Heine-Borel to conclude the result right after that which is weird to me since we are working the compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not $\mathbb{R}^2$ itself (iirc, Heine-Borel only holds for the standard topology).

4) (Bonus) Help me rename this question to something... better.

Comment: For a title, how about "Questions on the 1-point compactification of $\Bbb R^2$"... And the tag algebraic-topology is inappropriate.

Comment: BTW . If $X$ is a non-compact space then $X$ has a 1-point compactification  $Y$ such that $Y$ is Hausdorff, iff $X$ is a locally compact Tychonoff (completely regular space.  ...($X$ is locally compact iff every $p\in X$ belongs to an open subset $U$ of $X$ such that $\overline U$ is compact.... When $X$ is locally compact, Tychonoff, and not compact then $Y$ is called the Alexandroff compactification of $X$ and is often denoted $\alpha X$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thank you, I have made the appropriate changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) "Unbounded" is a property of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, not the one-point compactification. Note that $V_\beta$, the set described as unbounded, is obtained by applying $h$, which only takes values in $\mathbb{R}^2$. So unbounded means what it usually does: not contained in a ball.

2) Not very. When we take the one-point compactification, all of the sets that were open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ stay open. The only open sets that get added are the neighborhoods of $\infty$: complements of sets that were compact in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In particular, if you look at $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2\cup\{\infty\}$ with the subspace topology, you'll get back the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ we started with, since we didn't mess around with the open sets that don't contain the new point $\infty$.

3) If you're willing to assume what's been said previously in the paragraph (that $H$ is a homeomorphism and that $H(U_\beta)$ is open--it's worth working these out if you're not sure why), then since $H(U_\beta)$ is a neighborhood of $\infty$, it's characterized by the definition of the one-point compactification: it's the complement of a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. If you chase the definitions of things, you can see that this compact set, $\mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{\infty\} - H(U_\beta)$, is the same as $\mathbb{R}^2 - V_\beta$.

As for the application of the Heine-Borel theorem immediately afterwards, note again that we're working with $\mathbb{R}^2 - V_\beta$ and $\mathbb{R}^2 - h(C)$, which are subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, not its one-point compactification. You are correct that Heine-Borel only works on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

4) You might want the name to mention that you're working with one-point compactification.